# How can I apply a fragment shader to every pixel?

Tags: opengl, rendering

I have some transparent decals rendered into a separate framebuffer. Now I'm trying to blend this buffer with the back buffer (active target).

I'm assuming that I have to load the color buffer of the fbo as a texture in a fragment shader and output the texture color to the active target. **How can I tell the graphics card to do this operation for every pixel?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my code for the fullscreen rectangle/quad
this is old method - from OpenGL 1.1, but works :) For new OpenGL 3.* you have to use VBO/Arrays

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f( 0,0 );
glVertex3d( -1.0,-1.0, 0 );
glTexCoord2f( 1,0 );
glVertex3d(  1.0,-1.0, 0 );
glTexCoord2f( 1,1 );
glVertex3d(  1.0, 1.0, 0 );
glTexCoord2f( 0,1 );
glVertex3d( -1.0, 1.0, 0 );
glEnd();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
```

of course you have to setup textures before

Answer (score 3):

Draw a quad or two triangles that cover the whole screen.

Comment: Where and how big should I render them? I have a free moving camera. Some sample code or a link to a tutorial would be great.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an example and only know the direct x terms so hopefully someone better can explain... You don't use a camera just use -1, -1 to 1, 1. In your vertex shader just pass the coordinates through. In your pixel shader convert the coordinates into the range 0 - 1 to look up pixels in the texture... No need for any complex transformations